# Hide a certain category name from Related Posts

Tags: plugins, customization

I am trying to alter a plugin that has this code to display Related Categories names under the post:

```
<?php if ( count( get_the_category() ) ) : ?>
        <span class="cat-links">
            <?php printf( __( '<span class="%1$s">See related Videos</span> %2$s', 'posts-in-page' ), 'entry-utility-prep entry-utility-prep-cat-links', get_the_category_list( ', ' ) ); ?>
        </span>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Can someone please tell me how I can alter this code to exclude one Category name from the list that it generates...??
The category name that I want to exclude is "TopONLY" and its ID is 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$d = get_the_category();
$glu = [];
foreach($d as $rst ):
    //exclude category name
    if($rst->name != 'Sticky'):
    $glu[]="<a href=".get_category_link( $rst->cat_ID ).">{$rst->name}</a>";
    endif;
endforeach;

//error_log(print_r($glu, true).'/n', 3, WP_CONTENT_DIR.'/debug.log');
echo "These are the categories". implode(', ', $glu);
```

I'm a beginner. Hope this will help!

Comment: Appreciate the response. Please reformat your response within code blocks so I can better understand it. Also, please include your code within the code that I had originally posted.

Answer (score 0):

use `wp_list_categories` function instead and use 'exclude' argument.

use this code

```
<?php 
    $categories = get_the_category();
    $count=count($categories)
    if($count){
    foreach ( $categories as $category ) { 
    if ( $category->term_id == 11 ) { 
         continue;
    }?>
    <span class="cat-links">
        <?php printf( __( '<span class="%1$s">See related Videos</span> %2$s', 'posts-in-page' ), 'entry-utility-prep entry-utility-prep-cat-links', get_the_category_list( ', ' ) ); ?>
    </span>
<?php endif; 
}
?>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Appreciate the response but it is saying `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-content\themes\child\posts_loop_template_toponly.php ` So I added a semi-colon after the third line but now it is saying `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'endif' (T_ENDIF) in C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-content\themes\child\posts_loop_template_toponly.php on line 45`

Comment: <?php
$categories = get_the_category();
  
    foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
    if ( $category->term_id == 11 ) {
         continue;
    }?>
    <span class="cat-links">
        <?php printf( __( '<span class="%1$s">See related Videos</span> %2$s', 'posts-in-page' ), 'entry-utility-prep entry-utility-prep-cat-links', get_the_category_list( ', ' ) ); ?>
    </span>
<?php endif;
}

Use this one

Comment: Sorry, still getting the same error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'endif' (T_ENDIF) in C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-content\themes\child\posts_loop_template_toponly.php on line 34` This code that you have sent me has to go into a template file that is displaying various content on the page. I cannot change the other code in this template file and I also cannot change any shortcode. Any ideas...??

Comment: okay remove endif from bottom of code